# How do you manage and coordinate Android and iOS platform releases?

Tags: android, ios, release

In the context of managing and coordinating iOS and Android platform releases (for native apps):

1. What platform specific tasks would be included in pre and post release checklists?
2. What would be different in Pass/Fail criteria for different platform releases?

For different browsers I know you make sure to test in them but they are all served up by the same web server.  For native mobile apps I assume there will actually be specific procedures for each platform?

Answer (score 1):

#### Platform Specific

For iOS it's the app store.

For Android it's Google play - https://play.google.com/store/apps

#### Generally

Pre-release you might have:

- a list of common features that must work on each platform
- a list of specific features that must work on a given platform
- schedule of downtime for end users
- People and Technical resources needed to make the release happen and support it afterwards
- Platform specific testing

Post-release you might have:

- Monitoring of errors
- Monitoring of resource usage
- Additional human help for help lines

Pass/Fail criteria really depends on your business and the product.